# Access context outside render tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context

I have an app in React Native that uses many context. I want to access one of them within a non rendering function e.g. :

```js
const DataContext = React.createContext();

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // ...
      systemState: {},
      // ...
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const systemState = offlineSystemState();
    this.setState(systemState);
  }

  //   ...

  render() {
    return (
      <DataContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <CustomComponent />
      </DataContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

// OfflineSystemState component wants access to the DataContext,
// but impossible because it is not being rendered.
// Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
const offlineSystemState = () => {
  const context = useContext(DataContext);

  const systemState = processData(context.data);

  return systemState;
};
```

Is it possible to do this ? If not, is there a store that can do it (Redux, Mobx, ...) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After more than one year searching for a solution, my conclusion is that it is simply not possible.

Only solution is to pass dependencies directly to the non rendering service and the context to share one dependency instance.